# Job title mistake (a word missing) on my resume. Does it affect my background check?

Tags: job-offer, background-check, title, mistakes

Can anyone give me some opinions?

I am now a trainee in an information security department of a company. Also, I had been a data analyst trainee in another company.

Thus, when I was making my resume on my computer, I put down **"data analyst trainee"** in my resume. And then, I copied that and changed **"data"** to **"information security"** in another column. Yet, I forget to delete "analyst". It became **"information security analyst trainee"**

Now, the third company gave me an offer and asked me to fill in a form for background check.

In the form, I put down **"Trainee(information security)"**, which should be a more accurate job title, instead of **"information security analyst trainee"**

Is it a big mistake and going to affect my background check?

Comment: You corrected it by yourself without the people doing the background check having to come back about this.  Up date your CV so that it's correct from now on.

Comment: The mistake is that you wrote "information security analyst trainee" instead of "information security trainee"?

Comment: @Brandin Yep, I wrote "information security analyst trainee" instead of "information security trainee"

Comment: Does a background check even reveal job titles?  How would this process determine what your job title was? What is a job title anyway?  At some places they are super official and at others you can basically make up whatever you want so long as you perform the responsibilities required of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you not to worry about this mistake. Most likely it will remain unnoticed.

I assume that if you will try to correct the CV, you will need to send this document one more time which is really bad practice. In this case you can't just send CV but you will also need to include explanation why you send it again and point on your mistake.

Correct mistake in your CV for future but don't resend it.

Comment: Agree with this.  Is someone going to look at those two titles and say "wow, those are completely different jobs"?  Job titles are so non-standardized, I can't think that this would trigger a red-flag in a background check.  They're looking to see if you actually worked for employers, dates of employment, if you actually graduated with the stated degree from the schools listed, felony convictions, maybe bankruptcies (if relevant to the job).... not an exact job title, unless you are claiming to be a manger, director, or C-level executive, probably.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's highly unlikely that this will impact your application for the job in question.

Firstly, it's a minor typo.  If the interviewer even notices the difference while calling your past employers, he or she probably won't care.  (If the word "trainee" had been left out by mistake, that might be a different story, but having an extra "analyst" in there seems fairly harmless.)

Secondly - and I could be mistaken here - but if you're filling out a separate form for a background check, I believe that means they're going to conduct a criminal record check. Less to do with your actual job history, more to do with your own personal history.