# Job title discrepancy in background check

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, background-check, onboarding

I am currently going through the background check for a regulated role in a financial services consultancy. For one of my previous internships because I was given no title other than "intern" , I reformulated it as "rotating research analyst intern" on my CV to reflect the fact that I rotated across various teams.

When the background check company calls the HR of my previous company, they are only going to give the internal role name i.e. intern and this will cause a job title discrepancy. Do you reckon this will be a problem and I should inform the HR of the new company? I need to resign and trying to be cautious, thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Job title mistake (a word missing) on my resume. Does it affect my background check?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93108/job-title-mistake-a-word-missing-on-my-resume-does-it-affect-my-background-ch)

Comment: Is this question significantly different than your previous question? Or the multiple other questions asking about discrepancies in CVs and background checks?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. Just fill out the forms as accurately as you can when you fill out the job application/verification forms they give you.

Answer (score 5):

If the new company asks you about the discrepancy, just point out that your description is actually correct: "rotating research analyst **intern**". Point out to them that the word "Intern" is still there as the main word. The only thing you did was to add some additional info.

If the new company cannot understand that simple point of view, they will also not understand other more complicated matters in the future. In that case, be thankful that you got an early warning and had a chance to get out before being hurt.