# Pre employment Background screening question (HireRight)

Tags: background-check, pre-screening

### pre employment background screening question

Hi, had a question. Quite a complex situation so I apologies in advance and would appreciate any advise.

A few years ago I worked for a new company (joined a year after company was founded) and I had a official job title that was almost ”too creative” and basically not heard of in other companies. I was still doing what my actual job title was, alongside acting as a Junior for another role as they both go hand in hand in the job (instead of the company recruiting another full time person for the other role which they couldn’t justify doing). After a few months I asked my manager and HR if my official job title could be changed to something that was more relevant to what I was actually doing. However the leadership team and my manager kept saying we will discuss in your next 1-2-1, then next in my next review etc and it just didn’t happen. Although it was frustrating it was my first full time role after graduating and the experience was important so I carried on working there.

A few months later they recruited a Senior and I carried on doing my actual official role alongside spending a lot of my time helping the Senior with the more junior responsibilities. However my official job title still stayed the same.

During the pandemic I got made redundant as the company had to cut 50% of the workforce. I still have the redundancy letter which says I worked as the role that I was officially given.

I am in the process of currently going through some background screening checks with a big global company where I have wrote on my application and CV and on the form by the background screening company ”official title” / “junior in other role” which was unofficially given to me but I was doing, and have put down bullet points on my application and CV of what I did in both respective roles. The background company seem to be very thorough in their checks.

Because I have added this company as a reference for the company where I am in the process of going through screening checks, they will want to confirm my job title. In the background screening form I wrote both titles and have attached a copy of my redundancy form which only states the official title. Obviously the reference has to be factual with my official job title.

My concern is, will this come up as a discrepancy with the new employer? Obviously worried this will cost me a new job.

Any help is appreciated and happy to answer any questions. Also worth mentioning that the job offer is subject to satisfactory background checks (I have no jurisdictions, criminal history etc, always lived in the UK so no right to work issues, no bad credit history, nothing negative on my license etc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Job title discrepancy in background check](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/181917/job-title-discrepancy-in-background-check)

Comment: I'm voting to close as there are a few similar questions regarding background check discrepancies that have been asked before. However, I did just want to say - try not to stress about it, they're not trying to catch you out with this they usually just want to verify that you did work there

Answer (score 1):

Instead of showing positions and making them the highlight, you can focus on showcasing your work and experience and the skillset you have gained over the years.

Also, when you're going for a new job, never lie. State the facts but present them in a manner that they work in your favour and not against you.

We at [Iksana Workspaces,](https://pannal.work/) follow the same practice while hiring. We don't have problems accepting the failures of a prospective employee. But we need clarity on two things.

1. Employee's honestly
2. Their skillset

These are the two things that matter the most.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/118450)

Answer (score 0):

So long as you aren't:

1: Outright lying about your Job title and
2: Majorly inflating your job title.

I think you'll be fine.

The key thing is to provide detail where there appears to be a discrepancy - for example if your job title was officially Junior Whatever, but unofficially you were more like a full Whatever - what you can do during the process is point out what responsibilities you undertook *that were aligned with the more important job title*.

e.g. "Yes, my official job title was Junior Developer, but I undertook code review and I also planned a number of deployments and did these other duties that are more associated with a full Developer role"

Most companies understand that there's a grey area between roles and will be fine with this. Whereas if you put your job title as "Senior Development Architect" but your official job title was "Junior Developer" - then that's gonna be much more of an issue.